# Command not found “dotnet-dump”

Tags: .net, bash, ubuntu-20.04

Good afternoon.
Dotnet 6 was correctly installed on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

```
dotnet --version
6.0.400
```

Then, using the command, installed the utility **dotnet-dump**.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dump
```

Next, using the command, I try to get the version of the utility and I have an error:

```
dotnet-dump --version
dotnet-dump: command not found
```

If you try to install the utility again, you get a message that it is already installed:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dump
The dotnet-dump tool is already installed.
```

**Question:**

How do I fix this situation?

P.S.: The installation I carried out on the basis of the article [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-dump)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of steps to solve the problem:

1.Remove dotnet-dump utility;

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-dump
```

Note - I installed the utility globally, so the --global attribute is set when uninstalling.

2.Remove dotnet

```
sudo snap remove --purge dotnet-sdk
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-runtime
```

Note - Deleted in this way because it installed using the **snap** utility.

3.Installed dotnet using a script dotnet-install.sh ([enter link description here](https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh))

3.1 I give all rights (including execution) to the script file

```
chmod ugo+rwx dotnet-install.sh
ls -l
```

3.2 I run the script for execution

```
./dotnet-install.sh -c current
```

Note - In this case, -with current means that the latest SDK will be installed

3.3 Add the following text to .bashrc files and .bash_profile:

> export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/.dotnet
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT:$DOTNET_ROOT/tools

by executing the following commands:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc 
gedit ~/.bash_profile
```

4.Checking the version of the utility

```
dotnet-dump --version
```

Answer (score 4):

Ensure global tools dir is on the PATH

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
```

Comment: After executing the command, the contents of the PATH variable are :/sbin :/bin :/usr/bin :/usr/local/bin :/snap/bin :/root/.dotnet/tools :/home/anton/.dotnet/tools.

Comment: However, after executing the command: **dotnet-dump --version** The following text is provided: **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin:/root/.dotnet/tools
$ dotnet-dump --version
dotnet-dump: command not found
$ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
$ echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin:/root/.dotnet/tools:/home/anton/.dotnet/tools
$ dotnet-dump --version
Segmentation fault (core dumped)